# Running the "command" command as root using "sudo"

Tags: bash, sudo, command

How to execute the Bash command `command` using `sudo` in order to run it as root?

Using `sudo command` fails:

```shellsession
$ sudo command ls
sudo: command: command not found
```

Comment: Why do you need to run it with sudo? Do you want to do something like `command -v ...` to test if a command is available in the sudo environment?

Comment: I added an example of the failure that I imagine that you may see (taken from an Alpine Linux system). Please revise this if it does not correctly reflect what it is you are doing.

Answer (score 2):

The `sudo` command is able to run *an external command* as another user.  It can not be used to directly execute commands that are built into the shell. This also applies to the `doas` command on systems that uses it in place of `sudo`.

On some systems, the `command` command is available as an external command (`/usr/bin/command` on macOS, for example). On these systems, there would be no issue in using `sudo command ...`, other than the fact that it's not the shell's internal `command` command that is being executed, which could matter depending on what it is you are attempting to do.

On other systems, where `command` is *only* available as a command built into a shell, you may have to use `sudo` on the particular shell and in that way indirectly call that shell's built-in `command`:

```bash
sudo bash -c 'command ...'
```

Again, whether this does what you want depends on what it is you want to achieve.

Comment: To add to this, to verify whether a command is a shell builtin or an external command such as a binary in `/usr/bin`, use, in this case, `type command`.

Comment: @NasirRiley Note that `type command` (or `command -V command`) would say `command is a shell builtin` in shells where the command is a built-in, even though there is an external variant of the command available.  You would have to get the shell to _ignore_ the command in order to test whether there was an external variant of the command available. In Bash, you could use `(enable -n command; type command)`.

Comment: I understand. I was only stating that for this case, in which it's known which one is wanted, `type command` will identify it as a shell builtin. If that wasn't the case, then your method would apply. It's good to have this information anyway because both the shell builtin and `/usr/bin/command` operate very similarly.